# Is there an expand/collapse catch-all group in Solr?

Tags: solr

Given these example documents in Solr:

```
{id: 1, parent_id: 101}
{id: 2, parent_id: 102}
{id: 3, parent_id: 103}
{id: 4, parent_id: 104}
{id: 5, parent_id: 105}
{id: 6, parent_id: 101}
{id: 7, parent_id: 101}
```

I perform a Solr search using expand/collapse, creating a group for each parent_id, the total number of 3 groups with up to 10 documents in each:

```
...&expand=true&expand.rows=10&rows=3&fq={!collapse field=parent_id}
```

The results will look like:

```
Group 1: 
  {id: 1, parent_id: 101} (head document)
  {id: 6, parent_id: 101}
  {id: 7, parent_id: 101}
Group 2:
  {id: 2, parent_id: 102} (head document)
Group 3:
  {id: 3, parent_id: 103} (head document)
```

My question is: Is there a way to retrieve documents `id=4` and `id=5` in that query? I cannot simply increase the number of rows (groups), since I don't know how many groups there will be (it's 5 in this instance, but in reality that will vary). Is there any way to specify a "catch-all" group, which would contain the documents that passed my filters, but weren't assigned to any of the actual groups. So the results would have one extra group, such as:

```
Group Extra:
  {id: 4, parent_id: 104}
  {id: 5, parent_id: 105}
```

Notice this can't be handled by `nullPolicy`, since these documents have a valid (numeric) `parent_id`, they just didn't fit in the selected groups.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the source code, I do not see a catch all group. You can retrieve the documents you are looking for from the `response` section of the solrs response.

What is actually happening here, is that the collapsed documents do not show up in the expanded results. Have a look at `ExpandComponent.java`, this is intended:

1. In the `process` method, all original search results are added to `collapsedSet`
2. Later in the `collect` methods of the leaf collectors, these documents are skipped.

When you set the `expand.rows` parameter to > 0, the docs in the groups are returned with all attributes. So this behavior could be intended to not return documents twice, reducing the result size.

During my tests with Solr 8.11, groups with result size = 1 did't show up in the group section. So your groups 2 and 3 would not be present.